# Password Generator Error (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords, generator, password-generator

I dont know why I cant generate a custom password.

```
public void GeneratePass(View view) {

    EditText TextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DigitsField);
    int DigitsNum = Integer.parseInt(TextField.getText().toString());
    if (DigitsNum != 1){
        Random Pass = new Random();
        int num1 = Pass.nextInt(10);
        TextView PassText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PassText);
        PassText.setText(num1);
    }
}
```

I created this Text Field(EditText) In which you can write how many digits you want the password to be, I tried putting

```
    EditText TextField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DigitsField);
    String Digits = TextField.getText().toString();
    int DigitsNum = Integer.parseInt(Num);
```

and changing the if(DigitsNum == 1)... But when I write the digits(I just code for 1) I tried writing 1 but it just crash or stop working.

Comment: Replace TextField with textField better. DigitsField with digitsField. PassText with passText. Pass with pass. Digits with digits. DigitsNum with digitsNum... All these are mistakes

Comment: What your code does for now is that it will only generate a number ranging from 0 to 10. It is only one number.

Comment: from 0 to 9, but it just dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and modify it to your needs:

Java Code (Add this in your onCreate method):

```
final TextView passText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passText);
final EditText digitsField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.digitsField);
Button generatePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generatePassword);

generatePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int passwordLength = Integer.parseInt(digitsField.getText().toString());
        String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        char[] allowedCharsArray = allowedChars.toCharArray();
        char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
            chars[i] = allowedCharsArray[random.nextInt(allowedChars.length())];
        }

        passText.setText(chars, 0, passwordLength);
    }
});
```

XML Layout (Edit it with your current layout):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Password"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/passText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/digitsField" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate Password"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/generatePassword" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it give me an error, and because I am not so good at programming, I am just getting into it, I try to make it work but I cant.

Comment: Where is the error? Can you tell me? I'm just not on a computer right now so that was my random guess. Tell me where is the error and I'll definitely try to help. :) Also make sure that you fix the ids in your xmls as I mentioned as a comment in your question.

Comment: chars[i] = allowedChars[random.nextInt(allowedChars.length())];                           The error is in the first allowedChars.

Comment: @Pablo Sorry for the error. I have tested it now on my computer and everything is working fine! Try the updated code and don't forget to mark my answer as correct and vote it up if that works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you gave, but... there is a error, one, at                                 final TextView passText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passText);      but thanks for all the effort

Comment: @Pablo That code really works for me. I even tested it on my mobile. Make sure you wrote the id correctly in your xml. What does the error tell you? It must be a problem in your layout xml. Also make sure you wrote that code in onCreate.

Comment: @Pablo Did that code work for you? Because that worked for me... Tell me what you did. :)

Comment: It didnt work for me, could be because you used eclipse, I use android studio.

Comment: I use Android Studio. Also there is no difference if you used android studio or eclipse. Can you post your current code in your question? It's working for me.